# How to configure EF inheritence for nested relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to use table-per-type mapping pattern for 2 tables - Blog and Item. And Item is a relation with Blog. My entities:

```
public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();
    }

 public class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I enable TPT for both tables:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().UseTptMappingStrategy();
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().UseTptMappingStrategy();
```

And this are derived entitites:

```
public class RssBlog : Blog
    {
        public string RssUrl { get; set; }

        public List<RssItem> RssItems { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class RssItem : Item
    {        
        public string RssName { get; set; }

    }
```

This is sample code with expectation that EF will create 4 records (one per each table) in the DB. But this code failed with error insert or update on table "Items" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Items_Blogs_BlogId".

```
var rssBlog = new RssBlog()
    {
        RssUrl = "rssUrl",
        Url = "url",
        RssItems = new List<RssItem>()
        {
            new()
            {
                Name = "name",
                RssName = "rssname"
            }
        }
    };

    db.RssBlogs.Add(rssBlog);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

So what is a proper way to configuring inheritance with relations?

Comment: There's no inheritance relation between `RssItems` and `Items`. This isn't an EF issue - there's no inheritance between them in OOP terms, they're two completely unrelated properties. Inheritance means storing `RssItem`s in `Blog.Items`

Comment: Start by ensuring you have a good database design. Databases are far better at handling such relations than object oriented languages. In fact, the database typically outlives the application itself and quite often, the same tables are used by multiple application or even different models in the same application.

Comment: For example, is an Rss name really something that only belongs to a different type of blog item? Is an RssBlog a different type of blog? Or is RSS just an extra feature that can be associated with *every* kind of blog?